# Pattern matching on multiple values at the same time

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, we can use `when` to pattern match on a given value, e.g.,

```
when(value) {
    1 -> "One"
    2, 3 -> "Two or three"
    else -> "The rest"
}
```

We can also pattern match on multiple values at the same time by nesting the two values in a `Pair`.

```
when(Pair(value1, value2)) {
    (1, "One") -> "One"
    (2, "Two"), (3, "Three") -> "Two or three"
    else -> "The rest"
}
```

**Are there better ways of pattern matching on two values at the same time than nesting the two values in a pair?**

Comment: Is there any difference between this and your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58857567/pattern-matching-on-multiple-values-with-a-wildcard

Comment: I don't think there is currently a better option. I would simply improve the syntax to: `when(value1 to value2) { 1 to "One" -> "One" }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pattern matching on multiple values with a wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58857567/pattern-matching-on-multiple-values-with-a-wildcard)

Comment: I was not sure whether to split these questions, because there is a difference but it is small. My motivation to split them was that I think people are more likely to ask this question in the future so a standalone question would make it more simple to understand.

Comment: The difference lies in the focus on question 1) how to pattern match on the values in `when`; question 2) how to handle the `else` case but for only one branch in the value matching.

Comment: @Neo, it's a good alternative, but I'd hoped for something that didn't require the data to be wrapped in another data structure. But please post it as an answer so that more people will see it.

Comment: Kotlin has no support for pattern matching. The `when` construct is only superficially similar to how pattern matching looks in another languages.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a better solution, but a syntax suggestion to write the `Pair` example more elegantly (as requested in comment):

```
val value1 = 1
val value2 = "One"

when(value1 to value2) {
    1 to "One" -> "One"
    2 to "Two", 3 to "Three" -> "Two or three"
    else -> "The rest"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use the `when` pattern without parameter:

```
val value1: Int = ? 
val value2: String = ?

when {
    value1 == 1 && value2 == "One" -> "One"
    value1 == 2 && value2 == "Two" || value1 == 3 && value2 == "Three" -> "Two or three"
    else -> "The rest"
}
```