# Pattern matching on multiple values with a wildcard

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, we can use `when` to pattern match on a given value, e.g.,

```
when(value) {
    1 -> "One"
    2, 3 -> "Two or three"
    else -> "The rest"
}
```

We can also pattern match on multiple values at the same time by nesting the two values in a `Pair`.

```
when(Pair(value1, value2)) {
    (1, "One") -> "One"
    (2, "Two"), (3, "Three") -> "Two or three"
    else -> "The rest"
}
```

Now, I'd like to know how to pattern match on multiple values at the same time with a wildcard. 
I tried the following two approaches without success:

```
when(Pair(value1, value2)) {
    (1, _), (_, "One") -> "One"
    (2, _), (_, "Two"), (3, _), (_, "Three") -> "Two or three"
    else -> "The rest"
}
```

and

```
when(Pair(value1, value2)) {
    (1, else), (else, "One") -> "One"
    (2, else), (else, "Two"), (3, else), (else, "Three") -> "Two or three"
    else -> "The rest"
}
```

**How do I match any case for one of the variables?**

Answer (score 9):

Kotlin doesn't have the pattern matching capabilities that you might know from other languages. See here for a discussion on the feature: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/destructuring-in-when/2391/18

Your usecase isn't supported by `when`.